# Scanning text file into an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a text file, lets call it numbers.txt, and I need to scan it into an array.

numbers.txt (below is what is inside)

```
8 2 5 9 10 4 11 -1
```

The special value -1 indicates the end of the list.

I'm kinda confused on how to get it into my array. I know I need a loop, but can't put my head around it. Also, I am not scanning the file within the program, I am doing it within the terminal.

taylor> file < numbers.txt

So I would set it up like the user is inputting it.

```
 int main()
 {
    int numbers[50];
    int n, i;
    //scanf("%i", &n) 
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        //not sure what to do
    }
 }
```

Comment: A `fgets` and `sscanf` combo comes to mind...(Welp, you are doing input redirection, nvm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP needs to account for *many* stopping conditions.

1. Data read is -1 per OP's [deleted comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419674/scanning-text-file-into-an-array#comment71986240_42419718) "... I want it to stop once it its -1. So like `while(!=-1)` run the loop. I could do that with if statements as well." .  This is detectable by testing the value read.
2. Only up to 50 numbers.  Test the count of numbers read.
3. Not more input (end-of-file).  This is detectable by testing the `scanf()` return value of `EOF`.
4. Rare input error. (example, keyboard cable broke.)   This is also detectable by testing the `scanf()` return value of `EOF`.
5. If the input was non-numeric.   This is detectable by testing the `scanf()` return value of 0.
6. If the input text was in range of `int`.  Detection for this is not shown below.
7. Unclear if all data needs to be on one line, so detecting a `'\n'` is needed. Detection for this is not shown below.

Example

```
 int main()
 {
    int numbers[50];
    int i = 0;
    for( ; i < 50; i++) {
      int n;
      int conversion_count = scanf("%i", &n);
      if (conversion_count != 1) {
        break;  // End-of-file, input error, non-numeric input
      }
      if (n == -1) {
        break;
      }
      numbers[i] = n;
    }
    printf("%d numbers read.\n", i);
 }
```

Comment: That's better, I deleted my answer.

Comment: Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code does not compile! it is missing the `#include` statements

Here is a version of the code that:

1. cleanly compiles
2. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
3. checks for I/O errors and announces them on stderr
4. contains the needed `#include` statements
5. for readability and ease of understanding: separates code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line
6. removes unused variables
7. if/when reads the `-1` exits the read loop
8. avoids using 'magic' numbers, by giving them meaningful names

and now the code

```
 #include <stdio.h>  // scanf(), perror()
 #include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

 #define MAX_NUMBERS 50

 int main( void )
 {
    int numbers[ MAX_NUMBERS];
    int i;

    //scanf("%i", &n)
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBERS; i++)
    {
        if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &numbers[i] ) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for number failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        if( -1 == numbers[i] ) break;
    }
 }
```